# Windows Phone: How to draw a number on a wirteable bitmap?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a writeable bitmap (160x160) and a number in string. Code look like this:

```
WriteableBitmap pic1 = selectedPhoto.Crop(0, 0, 160, 160);
String s = "1";
```

I want to draw the string s onto the pic1.

How can I do??

Could you show me the way to solve my problem?

Thanks so much!

Input:

1. Writebale Bitmap
2. String

Ouput: view here: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2rX1vOBpbdw/US1zu88qOfI/AAAAAAAAAGs/hcsi2Jw3gDs/s512/p5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into using the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library. It's a series of extension methods that allow you do things like write text or shapes to the `WriteableBitmap`.

Comment: Thanks Alastair Pitts so much!

Comment: @KhắcPhục: No problem. Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer (using the green tick) if this helped :)

Comment: @KhắcPhục: Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer? Did this not work for you?

Comment: Yes, this is did not work for me. I need a number drawn onto an image look like this:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2rX1vOBpbdw/US1zu88qOfI/AAAAAAAAAGs/hcsi2Jw3gDs/s512/p5.png
But, after I follow the instructions of the article, results like this:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JkWBolaoFd8/UTAHXOaXYvI/AAAAAAAAAHM/Sb7GaWSI9P0/s134/Untitled.png

The original image was replaced, crushed loss!

Comment: Can you edit your original question with you updated test code?